# How to change directories with one click (not double) in LibreOffice?

Tags: linux, libreoffice

I use Linux KDE Plasma 5 with LibreOffice 5.2.4 now. In Plasma I set 'execute apps with one left click' or 'open directories with one click'.
Since long time I want to open (change) directories with one click only in LibreOffice for e.g. saving or opening a file but I cannot find any adaquate settings to manage this.
Anybody here, who knows how can I do this?
Thank you in advance.

-Linuxwhisperer

Comment: I'm using Kubuntu 16.04 (plasma 5.5.5 and libreoffice 5.1.6.2), and file dialogs support single click. Is Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice -> General -> Use LIbreoffice dialogs is unchecked?

Comment: @Ash: this is an (correct) answer (not omly a comment).
Please post it as such.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't understand, sorry. Do you mean settings of PLASMA itself for LibreOffice or Settings in menu bar of LibreOffice? I'm German, maybe I'm wrong with translation, but in "Extras - Optionen - LibreOffice - Allgemein" window 'Dialoge zum Öffnen / Speichern', LibreOffice Dialoge verwenden is unchecked. Nothing changes when I check it (mark it).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant, in LibreOffice itself. Got it from here: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/81/which-gui-toolkit-is-used-by-lo/. Not sure why my version works but yours doesn't.